# Кодировка с MySQL

Tags: mysql, кодировка, mysqli, utf-8

Проблема из разряда "Парился 5 часов и не нашел решение"

Из MySQL когда достаю данные - русские символы заменяются ?????????

Подскажите пожалуйста, так как в кодировках как раз мало разбираюсь, вроде везде где только можно проставлен единый utf8 , но увы

```
 <?php
//формируем заголовки документа - указываем, что кодировка UTF8
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

if (empty($_POST['commmand'])) exit;

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/db.php';

$data = array();

switch ($_POST['commmand']) {
case 'load-brunch':
    $pid = empty($_POST['parentID'])? 0 : $_POST['parentID'];
    $res = db_query("SELECT * FROM tree WHERE pID = :pid", array(':pid' => $pid));

    if ($res->num_rows) 
        while ($r = $res->fetch_object()) 
            $data[] = $r;

    break;
case 'load-object':
    $id = empty($_POST['objectID'])? 0 : $_POST['objectID'];
    $res = db_query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE IDobj = :id", array(':id' => $id));

    if ($res->num_rows) 
        $data = $res->fetch_object();

}

echo json_encode($data, true);
```

**а вот db.php**

```
<?php

global $db;

// Подключаемся к базе MySQL и выбираем базу 
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'ulogin_default', 'PASS', 'ulogin_baza');

if ($db->connect_errno) db_error();

function db_query($sql, $pairs = array()) {
    global $db;

    if (!empty($pairs)) {
        foreach ($pairs as $key => $value) {
            if (is_numeric($value)) {
                $sql = str_replace($key, $value, $sql);
            } else {
                $sql = str_replace($key, "'" . $db->real_escape_string($value) . "'", $sql);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!$result = $db->query($sql)) 
        db_error();

    return $result;
}

function db_error() {
    global $db; 

    echo "<pre>
        Извините, возникла проблема с подключение м к бд на сайте!\n";
    echo "Ошибка: Не удалсь создать соединение с базой MySQL и вот почему: \n";
    echo "Номер_ошибки: " . $db->connect_errno . "\n";
    echo "Ошибка: " . $db->connect_error . "\n</pre>";

    exit;       
}
?>
```

Comment: А вообще лучше замените utf8 на utf8mb4, так как просто utf8 не позволяет хранить Emoji и другие спецсимволы

Comment: в самой БД в Mysql так и сделано, но спасибо
когда нужны будут емодзи буду знать что прописать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить после коннекта `$db = new mysqli...`

```
$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

Comment: спасибо хороший человек - все заработало
счастья вам, здоровья)

жизнь продолжается, спасибо!!!!!